# How to add JLabel to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        JLabel label = ((JLabel)e.getSource());
        //searches for the label in the label arrayList 
        for(int i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++)
            if(labels.get(i) == label){
                JLabel newLabel = new JLabel();
                newLabel.setIcon(label.getIcon());
                newLabel.addMouseMotionListener(motionListener);
                modelPanel.add(newLabel);
                newLabel.setLocation(150, 160);
                newLabel.setVisible(true);
                modelPanel.revalidate();
                modelPanel.repaint();
                System.out.println("added" +modelPanel.getX()+ " " + modelPanel.getY());
                System.out.println(newLabel.getX() + " " + newLabel.getY());
            return;
            }                       
    }
```

the above code is supposed to create a new JLabel  and add it to the JPanel modelPanel. the System.out.println shows the object has been added but it fails to show on the screen during runtime.

modelPanel doesn't have a layoutManager as I am building an application that allows a user to drag and drop the created labels in any part of the modelPanel.

How do I make the JLabels show on the modelPanel?

Comment: *"modelPanel doesn't have a layoutManager as I am building an application that allows a user to drag and drop the created labels in any part of the modelPanel."* ..why? What is the application feature that you intend offering the user? The only thing I can think of is 'Drag-n-Drop GUI designer'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It is a Network Simulator that allows user to configure network models by dragging and connecting labels representing network devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a *null* `LayoutManager` means you need to do the job of the absent LayoutManager, this includes setting both the *location* and *size* of the child Component (the latter of which is not done in your code). A very simple example which dynamically adds JLabels to a null layout JPanel:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);
final int size = 400;
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("HERE");
        lab.setLocation((int)(size * Math.random()), (int)(size * Math.random()));
        lab.setSize(new Dimension(40,20));
        panel.add(lab);
        panel.repaint();
    }
});

frame.add(panel);
frame.setSize(size, size);
frame.setVisible(true);
timer.start();
```

Comment: (1+) You can also use the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) which helps simplify the process. It will manage the size of the component (by setting it equal to the preferred size) so you only need to worry about the location. If you do use the layout, then you would also need a `revalidate()` before the `repaint()`.